# Оборот с "будто" — нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, синтаксис

*Город будто был построен на магнитном поле, и весь транспорт левитировал.*

Правильно ли расставленны знаки препинания в предложении? Нужно ли обособлять "будто"?

Answer (score 1):

*Город будто (бы) был построен на магнитном поле, и весь транспорт левитировал.*

Никакого обособления не требуется. Союз *"будто"* разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, его можно заменить на *"словно".* Он совершенно не может служить вводным словом.

Обособляются сравнительные обороты с *"будто",* например:

> *И уже смешались облака и дымы, будто рядовые одного полка.* [В. В. Маяковский]

В Вашем случае такой оборот возникнет при перестроении предложения:

> *Весь транспорт левитировал, будто бы город был построен на магнитном поле.*

Comment: Спасибо большое, Артём Луговой

Comment: Не за что, Нара! Лучше просто по имени. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Артём всё верно сказал, однако хочу ещё добавить, что "будто" (аналог слову "словно") будет входить в состав составного именного сказуемого, характеризуя возможность данного события (частица, отражающая неуверенность) и являясь выразительным средством, служащим для связи двух понятий. Однако в данном случае я больше склоняюсь к роли выразительности, т. к. у нас присутствует вторая часть предложения, имеющая значение следствия.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, Бот Ботович